# N-ary tree template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, c++20, gcc12

For learning purposes, I'm trying to implement a similar class as the Value object in [micrograd](https://github.com/karpathy/micrograd). To be more precise, I'm trying to implement it in template metaprogramming.

So far, I'm able to do addition and multiplication with the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<double N>
struct Value {
    static constexpr double data = N;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Value &v) {
        os << "Value(data=" << v.data << ")";
        return os;
    }
};

template<double N, double R>
constexpr auto operator+(const Value<N> lhs, const Value<R> rhs) {
    return Value<lhs.data + rhs.data>();
}

template<double N, double R>
constexpr auto operator*(const Value<N> lhs, const Value<R> rhs) {
    return Value<lhs.data * rhs.data>();
}

int main() {
    Value<3.5> v;
    Value<2.0> w;

    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    std::cout << v + w << std::endl;
    std::cout << v * w << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the problem arises when I try to keep reference of the children for each `Value` object. For example, I would like to be able to do `v + w`, this would give me a new `Value` object with data equal to 5.5 and a list of children {v, w}. Furthermore, I would like to keep the children field generic and not assume any number of children. In other words, I'm trying to build a N-ary tree, not a binary tree. So right now, I have:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<double N, auto... Children>
struct Value {
    static constexpr double data = N;
    static constexpr Value children[sizeof...(Children)]{Children...};

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Value &v) {
        os << "Value(data=" << v.data << ", children=[";
        for (auto &&child : children) {
            os << child << ",";
        }
        os << "])";
        return os;
    }
};

template<double N, auto... Ns, double R, auto... Rs>
constexpr auto operator+(const Value<N, Ns...> lhs, const Value<R, Rs...> rhs) {
    return Value<lhs.data + rhs.data, lhs, rhs>();
}

template<double N, auto... Ns, double R, auto... Rs>
constexpr auto operator*(const Value<N, Ns...> lhs, const Value<R, Rs...> rhs) {
    return Value<lhs.data * rhs.data, lhs, rhs>();
}

int main() {
    Value<3.5> v;
    Value<2.0> w;

    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    std::cout << v + w << std::endl;
    std::cout << v * w << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and this gives me the following errors:

```
main.cc: In instantiation of 'constexpr const Value<5.5e+0, Value<3.5e+0>(), Value<2.0e+0>()> Value<5.5e+0, Value<3.5e+0>(), Value<2.0e+0>()>::children [2]':
main.cc:11:23:   required from 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Value<5.5e+0, Value<3.5e+0>(), Value<2.0e+0>()>&)'
main.cc:34:19:   required from here
main.cc:7:32: error: initializer for 'const Value<5.5e+0, Value<3.5e+0>(), Value<2.0e+0>()>' must be brace-enclosed
    7 |         static constexpr Value children[sizeof...(Children)]{Children...};
      |                                ^~~~~~~~
main.cc: In instantiation of 'constexpr const Value<7.0e+0, Value<3.5e+0>(), Value<2.0e+0>()> Value<7.0e+0, Value<3.5e+0>(), Value<2.0e+0>()>::children [2]':
main.cc:11:23:   required from 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Value<7.0e+0, Value<3.5e+0>(), Value<2.0e+0>()>&)'
main.cc:35:19:   required from here
main.cc:7:32: error: initializer for 'const Value<7.0e+0, Value<3.5e+0>(), Value<2.0e+0>()>' must be brace-enclosed
```

Unfortunately, I'm not understanding the error. It seems to say that I need to put braces around `Children...` but I already have some. If someone could give me a feedback on the error and maybe on how to improve the code, that would be highly appreciated.

## Edit

This is seems to be caused by the `operator<<` function when accessing the children property, not sure why, but this might give a lead to someone more experienced.

Comment: Note that Clang outright rejects `double` template parameters. Also note that if you add `-pedantic-errors`, your array is rejected for sometimes having zero size.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm mostly focused on gcc12. But thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Value<3.5>` and `Value<2.0>` are *different types*. You cannot have an array of elements of different types, i.e., you can't put `Value<3.5>` and `Value<2.0>` in the same array. You would either need to have an array of polymorphic base or a tuple. The latter comes with less (none) runtime overhead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<double N, auto... Children>
struct Value {
    static constexpr double data = N;
    static constexpr auto children = std::make_tuple(Children...);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Value &v) {
        os << "Value(data=" << v.data << ", children=[";
        std::apply([&os](auto const&... child) {
            ((os << child << ","), ...);
        }, children);
        os << "])";
        return os;
    }
};

template<double N, auto... Ns, double R, auto... Rs>
constexpr auto operator+(const Value<N, Ns...> lhs, const Value<R, Rs...> rhs) {
    return Value<lhs.data + rhs.data, lhs, rhs>();
}

template<double N, auto... Ns, double R, auto... Rs>
constexpr auto operator*(const Value<N, Ns...> lhs, const Value<R, Rs...> rhs) {
    return Value<lhs.data * rhs.data, lhs, rhs>();
}

int main() {
    Value<3.5> v;
    Value<2.0> w;

    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    std::cout << v + w << std::endl;
    std::cout << v * w << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

> ```
> Value(data=3.5, children=[])
> Value(data=5.5, children=[Value(data=3.5, children=[]),Value(data=2, children=[]),])
> Value(data=7, children=[Value(data=3.5, children=[]),Value(data=2, children=[]),])
> ```